# If senescent cells are removed by the immune system, how can they contribute to ageing?

Tags: senescence, immune-system

It is said that senescent cells, also called zombie cells, can cause biological ageing.  These senescent cells are also killed by immune cells. It does not make sense as to how they cause ageing if they are removed?

Comment: Who says that senescent cells are killed by the immune system? Do you have a source for that?

Comment: Here is a review article talking about immune killing of senescent cells....Cellular senescence: Immunosurveillance and future immunotherapy  https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1568163718300114

Comment: here is a link from a blog....https://www.fightaging.org/archives/2016/03/how-the-immune-system-recognizes-senescent-cells/

Answer (score 1):

In an healthy individual, senescent cells are likely removed by the immune system.  However, as we age, our immune system becomes impaired and may no longer be able to kill senescent cells.  Senescent cells can then accumulate and promote age-related diseases.